# Android - Custom AutoCompleteTextView CursorAdaptor - Suggestion Behavior

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to implement a custom AutoCompleteTextView for choosing a contact's phone number from a list of suggestions that display the contact name, phone number type, and phone number. I created a custom CursorAdapter that defines and sets my Layout and TextViews for each suggestion and queries contacts based on the user-entered text via runQueryOnBackgroundThread. I'm running into an issue where the suggestions seem correct for the first two values entered (e.g. "ab" suggests "abcd" and "abyz") but not for anything beyond that (e.g. "abc" suggests "abyz"). For the latter, when the "abyz" suggestion is selected, the values for "abcd" are returned.

Code for the main activity:

```
final ContactInfo cont = new ContactInfo(ctx);
    Cursor contacts = cont.getContacts2(null);
    startManagingCursor(contacts);

    ContactsAutoCompleteCursorAdapter adapter = new ContactsAutoCompleteCursorAdapter(this, contacts);
    mPersonText.setAdapter(adapter);
    mPersonText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            mPersonNum.setText(number);
        }
    });
```

Code for my contacts class that returns a cursor for all contacts:

```
public Cursor getContacts2(String where)
{
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

    Cursor people = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

    return people;
}
```

Code for my CursorAdapter:

```
public class ContactsAutoCompleteCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable {

private TextView mName, mType, mNumber;
private ContentResolver mContent;

public ContactsAutoCompleteCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    mContent = context.getContentResolver();
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    final LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View ret = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_auto_list, null);

    mName = (TextView) ret.findViewById(R.id.name);
    mType = (TextView) ret.findViewById(R.id.phonetype);
    mNumber = (TextView) ret.findViewById(R.id.phonenum);

    return ret;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int typeIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
    int numberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

    String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
    int type = cursor.getInt(typeIdx);
    String number = cursor.getString(numberIdx);

    mName.setText(name);
    if (type == 1) {mType.setText("Home");}
    else if (type == 2) {mType.setText("Mobile");}
    else if (type == 3) {mType.setText("Work");}
    else {mType.setText("Other");}
    mNumber.setText(number);

}

@Override
public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
    int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    String name = cursor.getString(nameCol);
    return name;
}

@Override
public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
    // this is how you query for suggestions
    // notice it is just a StringBuilder building the WHERE clause of a cursor which is the used to query for results
    if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) { return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint); }

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

    return mContent.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, 
            "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") LIKE '" + constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "%'", null, 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
}
```

}

As I said above, when the user enters "ab" into the AutoCompleteTextView the suggestions are "abcd" and "abyz", however when the user types "abc" the suggestion is just "abyz". When the user selects "abyz" in that case, the values for "abcd" are returned. Here are two screenshots that show what I'm trying to describe:

[image][image]

I've read every question I could find here and elsewhere but can't seem to figure this out. I'm fairly new to Android development so I apologize in advance if my mistake is a simple one. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have answered my own question after more research. Moving the setting of the views for my textViews from the newView function to the bindView function seems to have done the trick, which I think makes sense...

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    final LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View ret = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_auto_list, null);

    return ret;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int typeIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
    int numberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

    String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
    int type = cursor.getInt(typeIdx);
    String number = cursor.getString(numberIdx);

    mName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    mType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phonetype);
    mNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phonenum);

    mName.setText(name);
    if (type == 1) {mType.setText("Home");}
    else if (type == 2) {mType.setText("Mobile");}
    else if (type == 3) {mType.setText("Work");}
    else {mType.setText("Other");}
    mNumber.setText(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have already **public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread** function in your adapter so you do not need call second time cursor in activity

you do not need to use **getContacts2** function

**Activity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sms_send);

    Cursor contacts = null;

    mAdapter= new ContactsAutoCompleteCursorAdapter(this, contacts);
    mTxtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.mmWhoNo);
    mTxtPhoneNo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mTxtPhoneNo.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            mTxtPhoneNo.setText(number);

        }
    });


}
```

Adapter

```
public class ContactsAutoCompleteCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable {

private TextView mName, mType, mNumber;
private ContentResolver mContent;

public ContactsAutoCompleteCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    mContent = context.getContentResolver();
}




@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    final LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View ret = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custcontview, null);

    return ret;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int typeIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
    int numberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

    String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
    int type = cursor.getInt(typeIdx);
    String number = cursor.getString(numberIdx);

    mName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ccontName);
    mType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ccontType);
    mNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ccontNo);

    mName.setText(name);
    if (type == 1) {mType.setText("Home");}
    else if (type == 2) {mType.setText("Mobile");}
    else if (type == 3) {mType.setText("Work");}
    else {mType.setText("Other");}
    mNumber.setText(number);
}


@Override
public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
    int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    String name = cursor.getString(nameCol);
    return name;
}




@Override
public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
    // this is how you query for suggestions
    // notice it is just a StringBuilder building the WHERE clause of a cursor which is the used to query for results



if (constraint==null)
    return null;

    if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) { return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint); }

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

    return mContent.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, 
            "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") LIKE '%" + constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "%' or UPPER(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + ") LIKE '%" + constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "%' ", null, 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
}

}
```

i also add query for phone number search in query